# Relative source binding not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind the text property of one `textbox` to another via Relative source but its unsuccessful. Any one please let me know where I am doing it wrong.

**Please find the xaml code below:**

```
<Grid> 
<TextBox x:Name="testtextbx"
             BorderBrush="Green"
             Height="20"
             Text="test"                
             Margin="96,25,340,275">
    </TextBox>
    <Border Margin="55,54,64,63"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Red"
            >
        <Border Margin="82,32,69,36"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Black">
            <TextBox Margin="36,36,35,28"
                     Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TextBox},AncestorLevel=1},Path=Text}">
                     </TextBox>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: testtextbx is not a relative ancestor of the second TextBox so this won't work. Use ElementName as suggested by @tabby.

Comment: Although it doesn't make much sense, it would work with this Binding expression: `Text="{Binding Path=Children[0].Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @mm8 and @Lennart

> The second text box is not a relative ancestor of the first so this won't work

**You can Simply use:**

```
<TextBox Margin="36,36,35,28"
        Text="{Binding Text,ElementName=testtextbx}">
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, But I want to use it in relative source way and also want to know why my code was not working !!

Comment: @user3616471 The second text box is not a relative ancestor of the first. It's a nested sibling. The first text box doesn't contain the second.